# componentDidUpdate is receiving updates after I manually change things in MongoDB

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CustomerOverviewPage from "../components/customers/customerOverviewPage";

class CustomerView extends Component {
  state = {
    customer: null,
    id: null
  };

  fetchDetails = () => {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    fetch(`/api/customer/fetch-customer/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(customer =>
        this.setState({
          customer,
          id
        })
      );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDetails();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.fetchDetails();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.customer) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <CustomerOverviewPage
            id={this.state.id}
            customer={this.state.customer}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomerView;
```

I am curious to how this works since as I am new to ReactJS, but I have MongoDB setup through a sandbox account on MLAB and if I go in there and manually remove a record or edit a record, my DOM updates to reflect it.

In this case I am manually modifying my customers collection and updating the name. It's re-rendering that CustomerOverviewPage component.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, as soon as your application finishes rendering, after a state change, it calls `componentDidUpdate`. Since this calls for the `fetchDetails`, which in return updates the state again, it causes an infinite loop of re-rendering. When you update your collection manually it's reflected on the application because it's always in a loop of fetching.

Here's an [image](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*u8hTumGAPQMYZIvfgQMfPA.jpeg) showing the lifecycle of a react application.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was I had multiple `componentDidMount()` in subcomponents, which was causing the primary one to see an update and render() again and again.